# How to show already selected data in MUI datagrid checkboxSelection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I am using Datagrid in React webapp, I want few rows already selected on the Data grid as they were selected on previously.
[image]

Right now the user has access to Server A,C and D.
How do I make it happen.
Here is the code:

```
<DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    autoPageSize
    disableColumnMenu
    paginationModel={{ page: 0, pageSize: 15 }}
    checkboxSelection
    onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
        const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
        const selectedRows = rows.filter((row) =>
          selectedIDs.has(row.id),
        );
        setSelectedRows(selectedRows.map((rowdata)=>(rowdata.name)));
      }}
  />
```

Please help me out here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you try using `useEffect(() => {setSelectedRows(...any_rows_you_want_here)}, [])`?

Comment: That will not work coz we are not passing selectedRows as input to DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken some time to dig into your problem and found a solution that works.

Use `selectionModel`, like this:

(`selectedRows` should actually be your state)

```js
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid'

const rows = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alice', age: 15 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Bob', age: 25 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Charles', age: 35 },
]

const selectedRows = [1, 3] // Select rows with ids 1 and 3.

export default function Test() {
    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
                <DataGrid
                    rows={rows}
                    autoPageSize
                    disableColumnMenu
                    paginationModel={{ page: 0, pageSize: 15 }}
                    checkboxSelection
                    columns={[
                        { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name', width: 150 },
                        { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name', width: 150 },
                        { field: 'age', headerName: 'Age', type: 'number', width: 90 },
                    ]}
                    selectionModel={selectedRows}
                />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```